# RazorPage & mvc isn't async look like

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
        _logger.LogInformation("begin");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
}
```

Get the page in the same time：

```
[11:32:05 INF] begin
[11:32:10 INF] begin
```

and ApiController is same.
why not async look like?

Comment: Please post your full code. How to do you call the `OnGetAsync` method?

Comment: What is your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may use the same browser to test this action.

I suggest you could try to use different browser or private mode for the browser to test and you will find its async.

It depend on how the asp.net core handle the request, not related with async, but async will increase the web application performance.

[image]